# Private Information in a Publicly Available Source Code

Tags: java, encryption, open-source

We decided to make our source code available to the public, via github. We have some information that we can't share to the public, for example email used by our application to send email and some social media credential. What would be the best thing to do to keep the information private?

We are using java in app-engine on our application.

Comment: Just separate your code and configuration, i.e. have it in a file which isn't shared on github.

Comment: You may also ask for configuration at the startup of program, in case it is not set in properties file. But in case you want to make code public AND have that code to include THAT magic email, then you're out of luck. In that case you should have your app communicating with some proxy, that adds this data to apps' information, or passes info both ways with social media site. Then you could have some custom authentication that is translated for emailing or socialmediaing.

Answer (score 6):

Keep that data in property files that are either on your local machines or in a different, non-public repository.

Comment: This.  If you don't want the info public, don't put it in a public repo.

Answer (score 1):

Read this data from a property file or database and don't include the file/database in your source repository. If you have previously committed your codes with private information in your repository, you will need to create new repository which contains no history of any private information. There is no way to strip off those information from the exisitng repository and keep your history as far  as I know.

Answer (score 0):

Encrypt information that you want to keep private with [`AES Crypt`](http://www.aescrypt.com/) and try not to leak references in your code (Have the decryption come from another source that isn't local preferrably via an API, if you can).

Comment: At some point, that data will have to be decoded/decrypted -- using data provided by the repo -- or having it in the repo is useless anyway.

Comment: Good point. I'm not really sure, why any body would want to hard code email username/password etc into an application any way? why not create a user interface and allow the user to input their own email/password to send emails?

Comment: because it is simpler for a test project and once you realise that you shouldn't have done that it's too late.